# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#get on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_firestore)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am stuck on an awkward situation while trying to implement `cloud_firestore` in my project.

while I am running the app in the emulator and add the dependency to the project it compiles without any error but I am unable to make any task through it.

Whenever I am trying to perform some code of firestore it sows some error

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#get on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_firestore)
```

to resolve this error i was trying to again after killing the process
then it show some big error on compilation
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73799777/execution-failed-for-task-cloud-firestorecompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-flutte) is the question regarding this issue on stackoverflow

Most important thing is that again tried running the app removing `cloud_firestore` plugin then it works smoothly like previously also I am able to add the package in the running process but same error occurs.

I am not using firebase auth before calling the `FirebaseFirestore` class

used packages are mentioned in the previous question.

Anyone please help me out to resolve this question

Comment: please refer this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59913165/i-flutter-22027-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method-doc) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73539884/flutter-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method-documentrefer/735423400) and this github [link1](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/1903)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya all of these solutions are tried already

Answer (score 0):

just remove the app from your device and reinstall it. I think it will solve your problem!!!

Comment: it also didn't work